# I cannot update wordpress plugin after fix ftp client login

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp

Well my problem is this after fix wordpress asking me for FTP user and password doing this: [Wordpress asking for my FTP credentials to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins)

Wordpress no longer asking me for FTP user and password but surprise to me I have another error this one it said after downloading the update for the plugin: **Could not create the directory**

I don't know if this normal after fixing the FTP on that way or if this can be fix. Another important thing is that I was doing this in a localhost just for learn how to use wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if same name directory already exist? then delete that then try. Also check that root folder permission and set permission proper so it allow to create directory.

Comment: Excuse me but where I can check if that folder already exist. if is just an update I really don't know. Second when you said root folder you mean the wordpress folder right if is that the only thing that I do was change the owner and the group to wwww-data both. I don't know what else I can do

Comment: I am talking about that plugin folder.I know that plugin update doe not require to remove folder but based on error message which you have given , I suggested you. Also root folder means - wp-content folder.

Comment: Exactly. I use chown -R and the problem was solve. Because I try to delete manually but problem remains. so I changed ownership of all folders and it works. Thank you very much for the comment

Comment: Now I have another unrelated problem I guess. I can't updato to version 4.0.1 because I have problem with this file: licenses.txt. I do the same but this time it does not work