# WordPress needs to access your web server- already tried all methods

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

[image]

[image]

i already have tried all methods form this link- ([Wordpress asking for my FTP credentials to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins))
but no one is working. please help me if you can. Note: i am using amazon AWS amazon linux.

Comment: It simply asks for your Server FTP account information. If you installed WP in a hosting, then you should already have it. Call your hosting provider to get it. dont complicate things, just find your FTP info and insert them

Comment: so you want to create FTP for aws ec2 right? , this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp 
and what is your problem ? cannot you install/update plugins?

Comment: I don't use ftp - ftp is horrible - I have not used amazon recently but had similar issues on other hosts that were solved by me making sure that the www user had ownership or write privileges on the www directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install an FTP server (vsftpd through yum is easy enough - a simple guide is at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-centos-6--2), create user credentials, and create a security group rule to open port 21 to 0.0.0.0/0 (unless you know the host from which Wordpress will connect to your site and in that case restrict the security group rule to that IP address).

Comment: Yes..i can do it but i am looking for something more easy