# WordPress FTP connection setting for localhost to upload and install WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ftp, connection, credentials

I can't upload a WooCommerce .zip file and install the plugin on the local host. Every time I click install button, WordPress is asking for connection information for the FTP credentials like this picture:

[image]

Even though I entered localhost for the hostname and admin as username, it doesn't work!

Comment: Is your localhost a Linux machine?

Comment: I got a mac OSX Sierra

Comment: I no nothing about Macs but WordPress will usually directly install files and only uses FTP when it does not have write access to the install directory. Does the process running the WordPress server have write access to your  plugin directory? You can avoid using FTP if WordPress can directly write to your plugin directory. Sorry, don't know how to do this on a Mac.

Comment: It's okay thank you, I've found the solution as you see I added the answer. Thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/
```

Then add these to `wp-config.php`:

```
/** Add here*/
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", “my_wordpress_user”);
define("FTP_PASS", “password”);
/** To here*/
```

In the line above, `my_wordpress_user` and `password` are the ones used in wordpress.

Comment: Using `chmod 777` to fix permissions issue is a lack of understanding the real problem. See a more detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access#answer-5650020 and also @Sebastian Schmid comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins/18634804#18634804

Comment: Thank you so much, Work for me

Answer (score 6):

Ok I solved the problem by editing **wp-config.php** in the htdocs folder where I installed Wordpress -> like image 1:

[image: image1]

I added the below lines to the **wp-config.php** like image 2

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", "admin");
define("FTP_PASS", "1234");
```

[image: image2]

**The username and password is the same as the username pass when I installed the Wordpress during the installation.**

Answer (score 6):

Just add `define('FS_METHOD','direct');`  into your wp-config.php.

Answer (score 1):

Recommanded:

If you are using centos:

```
//Set www to 777
# chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
// Change the owner to apache
# chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
// Restart httpd
# systemctl restart httpd
```

Not recommanded but works:

Add this line in wp-config.php

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```