# Upload a theme without FTP

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded a theme and I'd like to install it.
Now I'm in Appearance > Themes > Add > New/Upload Theme.
WordPress wants an FTP access.
Well, I'm at my local machine and no FTP server is listening the port 21.

I'm inspired by this post:
[Can I install/update WordPress plugins without providing FTP access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640409/can-i-install-update-wordpress-plugins-without-providing-ftp-access)

So, they say that after granting write permissions, no FTP prompt will appear.

For simplicity of the **learning (!)** process I've allowed everything on the directory now.

```
michael@hp:/var/www/html$ ls -la | grep wp-content
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root  4096 дек 20 20:50 wp-content
```

Well, WordPress continues to ask for FTP access.
Could you give me a kick here?

Comment: You can upload themes zip files directly through the administration area.

Comment: Well, pardon if I was a bit obscure. I'm already in the WordPress dashboard. I'll modify my post a bit.

Comment: ssh into the server?

Comment: I see. Try setting the ownership of the directory to your local server group/user

Comment: mehulmpt, no. I'm on my local machine with a desktop Ubuntu.

Comment: Douglas Santos, I have done sudo chown www-data wp-content/. Now the picture for ls -la is: drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data root  4096 Dec 20 21:24 wp-content. The same prompt for FTP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/

Comment: Douglas Santos, thank you. It really did the job. I was inattentive. If you organize your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accepted it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check, that `httpd user` have permission "rw" to `wp-content` folder and add into `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```