# Wordpress asking for FTP credentials when trying to install a theme

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

Before I get started, I'd like to say that I tried almost every solution I could find for this problem but had no luck with them. The most popular solution was adding define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' ); to the wp-config.php file but that didn't work either :(

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Both, my co-worker and I installed WordPress at the same time, she's getting nothing like this, maybe cuz she is using a windows machine and I'm using a Mac? And also, I'm using Xaamp. I'm really new to all so any kind of feedback is appreciated! :)

Comment: Check your firewall and add accessing to WP folder from http requests

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to post here: [WordPress asking for my FTP credentials to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins)

The solution to this problem for me was my php-fpm configuration. I had the php-fpm user and group set to "www-data" (nginx user) at /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/user1.conf. I changed both the user and group in the php-fpm configuration to the linux user I created (i.e. /home/user1/) for this app.

I hope this helps someone because it was not listed in the most popular topics in stack.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31624680)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The link does not provide an answer. I will remove it, because it is confusing. The answer is in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

A quick search on stackoverflow found this:

[WordPress asking for my FTP credentials to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922644/wordpress-asking-for-my-ftp-credentials-to-install-plugins)

There are a number of different solutions you can try which may resemble your issue with relation to MacOSX.